# ModelAndView.addObject vs Model.addAttribute

Tags: spring-mvc

Good day, I'm learning Spring MVC and I'm writting my tiny webapp following [this tutorial](http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2013/07/spring-jdbc-template-with-spring-mvc.html) but I slightly modified it as a "list of tasks" and not "list of users". One thing is not clear to me so I'd like to ask for an explanation. This is my edit.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>  
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>  
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Edit task</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Edit task</h1>
    <form:form method="post" action="/update" modelAttribute="task">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Title</td>
                <td><form:input path="title"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Description</td>
                <td><form:textarea path="description"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Save"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is method editTask in my HomePageController.java (version 1):

```
 @RequestMapping("/edit")  
 public ModelAndView editTask(@RequestParam String id, @ModelAttribute Task task) {  
   // Retrieve task from the database
     task = taskService.getTask(id);
     ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("edit");
     model.addObject("task", task);
     return model;
 }
```

If I click on edit link to edit an item (e.g. /TaskBook/edit?id=1) a form appears but it is not populated. So I changed the method this way (version 2):

```
 @RequestMapping("/edit")  
 public String editTask(@RequestParam String id, Model model) {
     Task task = taskService.getTask(id);
     model.addAttribute("task", task);
     return "edit";
 }
```

Now the form is populated when I edit a task. I don't understand what's the difference between model.addObject("task", task) in version 1 and model.addAttribute("task", task) in version 2. Is the task object stored somewhere else or is it lost? Please explain. I use Spring Framework 3.2.1.

Thank you in advance. Vojtech.

EDIT: 
If I change editTask() to code below it works - the form is populated. But what if some task data were submited, how can I read them now?

```
@RequestMapping("/edit")  
public ModelAndView editTask(@RequestParam String id) {  
  task = taskService.getTask(id);
  ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("edit");
  model.addObject("task", task);
  return model;
}
```

Comment: Do me a favor and test your first `editTask()` but remove the `@ModelAttribute` parameter. Instead create the `Task` reference in your method. See what happens.

Comment: I changed editTask() - see edited post above - and the form is still not populated.

Comment: No that has the same effect. Get rid of the `Task` parameter completely. Use as `Task task = taskService.getTask(id);` in the method. Also, putting code in comments is hard to read. Consider editing your answer instead.

Comment: So I removed Task parameter and it started work. So it probably means that task set by model.addObject("task", task) was somewhere owerwritten by task passed as parameter, correct? And how can I read task data if there were some submitted now?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You've hit an edge case that doesn't occur very often. Let's go by try

```
@RequestMapping("/edit")  
public String editTask(@RequestParam String id, Model model) {
    Task task = taskService.getTask(id);
    model.addAttribute("task", task);
    return "edit";
}
```

In this case, Spring will create a `Model` object from its `ModelAndViewContainer` and pass that as an argument to your method. So if you had model attributes added earlier, they would be available to you here and the ones you add in will be available later. You return a `String` view name. Spring will use that String with a `ViewResolver` to resolve which `jsp` or other type of view to render or forward to.

With this

```
@RequestMapping("/edit")  
public ModelAndView editTask(@RequestParam String id, @ModelAttribute Task task) {  
    // Retrieve task from the database
    task = taskService.getTask(id);
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("edit");
    model.addObject("task", task);
    return model;
}
```

Spring, because of the `@ModelAttribute`, will create a `Task` object and pass that as an argument when invoking (reflection) your method. The `ModelAndView` object you create, add to, and return will be merged with the `ModelAndView` object contained in the `ModelAndViewContainer` that is managed by Spring for your request. So things you add here will also be available later.

**The hitch:** It appears `ModelAttribute` has priority on the model attributes, so it doesn't get overwritten by the model attributes you add to the `ModelAndView` object. Actually **it** gets written to your `ModelAndView` object, overwriting your `"task"` attribute. Remember that if you don't specify a `value` attribute to `@ModelAttribute` annotation, it uses the type of the argument to give it a name. For example, `Task` ==> `"task"`, `List<Task>` ==> `taskList`, etc.