# Form with a select (drop-down) doesn't show error code

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a form that contains a select to list all teachers by id in the system but it is not working properly.

Here is the code part of the form

and the corresponding path controller requests

I'm Using Thymeleaf and Spring Boot, so 'pr' corresponds a name for a variable of a repository of teachers.

```
<form th:action="@{/professor/updateProfessor/}"  method="post" th:object="${professor}">
        <div class= "form-group">
        <label th:for = "id">Id</label>
        <select th:field="*{id}">
            <option
            th:value = "${id}"
            th:text = "${professor.id}">
            </option>
            </select>
        </div>      
        <input type = "submit" value = "Add Professor">Save</button>
    </form>


@GetMapping(value = {"/selecionaProfessor"})
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView professorSelecao(){
    ModelAndView atualizaProfessor = new ModelAndView("/atualizaProfessor");
    atualizaProfessor.addObject("Add Professor");
    return atualizaProfessor;
}

@PostMapping(value = {"/selecionaProfessor"})
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView selecaoProfessor(){
    ModelAndView pagSucesso = new ModelAndView("/pagSucesso");

    pagSucesso.addObject(pr.findAll());
    return pagSucesso;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your controller, send a list of professors as per following to your view. Here you are associating the list of professors to the "professorList" :

```
model.addAttribute("professorList", pr.findAll());
```

And then to access above "professorList" in your thymeleaf do (similar to) this :

```
<option th:each="professor: ${professorList}" th:value="${professor}"> </option>
```

Not a full code but i hope you got the idea to get started.

For a full example, take a look [here](https://github.com/ajkr195/Code-Incubator/blob/master/src/main/java/com/code/incubator/controller/AppController.java) and [here](https://github.com/ajkr195/Code-Incubator/blob/master/src/main/resources/templates/home.html).

Comment: Thank you! :)
Let me ask you... Theres no way to do the same using addObject method?

Comment: There are always possibilities. :-) take a look at this for a little more insight - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183747/modelandview-addobject-vs-model-addattribute

Answer (score 0):

First of all what is not working? because I see a lot of things that may not work maybe because I don't see the all code or I am guessing some things, let's see

When you enter to your controller using

```
 localhost:8080/professor/selecionaProfessor
```

are you expecting to use the form you put right? (the next code)

```
<form th:action="@{/professor/updateProfessor/}"  method="post" th:object="${professor}">
    <div class= "form-group">
    <label th:for = "id">Id</label>
    <select th:field="*{id}">
        <option
        th:value = "${id}"
        th:text = "${professor.id}">
        </option>
        </select>
    </div>      
    <input type = "submit" value = "Add Professor">Save</button>
</form>
```

because if that's correct you have a problem in your method:

```
@GetMapping(value = {"/selecionaProfessor"})
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView professorSelecao(){
   ModelAndView atualizaProfessor = new ModelAndView("/atualizaProfessor");
   atualizaProfessor.addObject("Add Professor");
return atualizaProfessor;
}
```

you will get an error saying:

```
Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'professor' available as request attribute
```

So you're missing to add the Key professor and a List so change:

```
   atualizaProfessor.addObject("Add Professor");
```

with something like:

```
atualizaProfessor.addObject("professor",   someListOfProfessorHereFromTheService (List<Professor>));
```

and it should work if your profesor object have the attributes you have on your form.

Now let's suppose that that worked before and the error wasn't that.

When you enter to your form if you see here:

```
 form th:action="@{/professor/updateProfessor/}"
```

you're using updateProfessor I don't see that on your controller you have

```
  @PostMapping(value = {"/selecionaProfessor"})
```

So I think that you should change the url mapping inside the html page or the controller and use the same as error 1, map the object using a key and value and iterate the list into the html as I showed in the 1st error

Hope it helps