# SPRING MVC: returned ModelAndView/parameters precedence

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm new in Spring, and I'm trying to better undestand the MVC framework.
Considering the following jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>Hello World!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Welcome <%=request.getAttribute("username")%>
    </body>
</html>
```

I see that, in a @Controller class:

```
@GetMapping("/EntryPoint1")
public String helloView1(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("username", "pippo");
    return "HelloWorld";

}
```

it uses as `username` value the one inserted in  `model`.

However, if I declare both the `Model model` parameter and I return a `ModelAndView` object, that is:

```
@GetMapping("/EntryPoint2")
public ModelAndView helloView2(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("username", "pluto");
    
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("HelloWorld");
    mav.addObject("username", "paperino");
    return mav;

}
```

I obtain that the value used by the view is the one contained in `mav` ignoring the value in `model`. Is there an explanation for this (for example, any kind of precedence between the  objects considered by the view)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see, here in model.addAttribute("username", "pluto");
and in mav.addObject("username", "paperino");
username is same so priorities goes to ModelAndView, However u change the name then u can render them both and access.

Comment: @volperossa  For further details [refer this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183747/modelandview-addobject-vs-model-addattribute)